# Android app unjustifiably rotates to landscape and then back to portrait

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android app unjustifiably rotates to landscape for a split second and then returns to portrait. This happens when returning to the app from the camera.

```
    public void configureItemImageButton() {
    MaterialCardView itemImageButton = (MaterialCardView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImageCardView);
    itemImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 111);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 111) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Below is my android manifest file:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_trainsterlogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <activity android:name=".TrainsterActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </uses-permission>
```

EDIT: This problem did not occur if my editTextview had text in it, however I can no longer reproduce this, and I tried removing the textview and the problem persists.

EDIT: I have negated it's negative affect of clearing my image by saving the instance. However the unexplained rotation continues to be aesthetically unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest file under that particular activity

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I already tried that to no avail.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the post